# Why is keras and BatchNormalization underlined?

Tags: python, keras, pycharm, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I am trying to run a CNN python code, but at the top of the code, the following line has keras and BatchNormalization underline in red.

```
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
```

I don't know why there are underline. I confirmed that I have python, keras and tensorflow installed

```
>>> import keras
>>> keras.__version__
'2.8.0'
>>> 

>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf. __version__)
2.8.0
>>>

(venv) PS C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Local-Binary-Patterns> python --version
Python 3.10.4
>>
```

Am I missing something?

```
Computer specs: HP Omen with Ryzen 7 CPU and GEFORCE RTX 3080 GPU.
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should import BatchNormalization like so -

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
```

Comment: So I did, and now BatchNormalization is underlined

Comment: you added the `.normalization` that I think you should get rid of

Comment: So It looks like this:

from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization

Answer (score 0):

If the code works, don't worry about the underline.

TensorFlow uses some late-import and aliasing tricks that sometimes confuse PyCharm's code completion system.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to revert to old versions of Python, Keras and Tensorflow

```
Python: 3.9.0
Keras: 2.4.3
Tensorflow: 2.5.0
```

I then copied my python code and ran it with the new versions and it worked like a charm.